# Streaming file from URI directly to S3 using lambda using ridiculous amount of memory

Tags: node.js, amazon-sns, aws-lambda

I was able to stream files directly from a URI to S3 without downloading it on disk with AWS Lambda (node.js) using [this guys sample code](https://gist.github.com/sevastos/5804803). I modified it a bit so I could create a buffer from a request object body. [This is my code](https://gist.github.com/maxKimoby/b19495a0a3af522a5076).

It works wonder except for a very important thing! The files are maximum 350 MB, but every time the lambda function run, it takes up to 1.5 GB memory and even more! The maximum allowed memory for a function call is 1.536 GB. The amount normally used is between 0.8 GB to 1.5 GB (it is pretty random).

I think there is a memory leak somewhere, but I can't figure out where!

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm no node.js expert but `var buffer = new Buffer(body);` is making a copy of the entire body in memory, so that right there will double the RAM you need, won't it?  `request` should return `body` as type buffer which I assume you could use directly without copying it to a new buffer, or it should be possible to ask for it to, maybe with `encoding: null` (note, I'm making this up, while reading the docs).

Comment: You got it straight on. I can't thank you enough! I was recreating a buffer from the body when the returned body of a request can already be used as a buffer. Your reasoning was perfect, I was duplicating the allocated memory for the buffer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var buffer = new Buffer(body);` seems to be making a copy of the entire response body in memory... doubling the amount of memory you'll need.

[request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) appears to provide (or be configurable to provide) `body` as a [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html), so you should be able to use `body` directly, rather than duplicating it in memory by creating a second buffer.

Comment: Answer was given in OP comments but I'll accept this answer as I can't accept a comment as the answer! Thanks.

Comment: The comment was mostly a guess, until you confirmed that it was a good one. :)